# How long does jsFiddle host your code for?

Tags: jsfiddle

I have been using [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to assist in helping answer questions around Stack Overflow, and some of the old code/scripts have started disappearing - seems like it expires after a certain length of inactivity.

I tried looking at the jsFiddle [documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net), and searching Google, but couldn't find any info on how long they store the scripts for.

Does anyone happen to know how long jsFiddle hosts your code for?

Comment: Ask on their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/jsfiddle)

Comment: [My oldest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xDHr2) just turned a year old and is still available. So there's a benchmark for you...

Comment: It's a lot longer than a month.  I have some that are close to a year old.

Comment: I think that it must be based on if you have an account or not?

Comment: Just lost a script that I had been working on for barely 10 minutes.  This is not a service I'm going to recommend, based on everything I'm seeing here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

According to the developer (via twitter [tweet 1](https://twitter.com/?iid=am-66429244813216599221282233&nid=4%20status_user&uid=19116343&utm_content=profile#!/js_fiddle/status/137668000194113536) & [tweet 2](https://twitter.com/?iid=am-66429244813216599221282233&nid=4%20status_user&uid=19116343&utm_content=profile#!/js_fiddle/status/137677807634481153)):

> Until beta, all fiddles are stored permanently. And, currently, they live forever.

Comment: That said, we're still thinking about making fiddles live forever after beta hits. We're probably going to store them till the end of time.

Comment: @OskarKrawczyk for some reason all fiddles [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13681917/447356) are gone, is this because the user deleted his jsfiddle account? Other jsfiddle stored scripts appear to be intact even older so it's not matter of time..

Comment: @ShadowWizard The only fiddles that will be kept indefinitely the ones created anonymously. We currently have no option to remove an account so those fiddles are gone because they were actively deleted by the owner. His public fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/user/hashie5/fiddles/

Comment: @OskarKrawczyk thanks, wasn't aware one can manually delete his fiddles.

Answer (score 1):

See complains about availability of JS Fiddle at:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Today my weekly old fiddles are dead (from question [Align to right "left triangle" in menu element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006130/align-to-right-left-triangle-in-menu-element)).

Any service have maintenance cost. So you can't have any guarantee unless you make agreement with service provider.

Comment: This was a DDOS attack, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179964/my-jsfiddle-page-returns-404-registration-required/25181020#25181020