# jQuery Cycle with HTML Content

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using jQuery Cycle on a full width image slideshow.

What i'd like to do is have some HTML text within a div and when the transition "scrollUp" occurs, So does the text. I have tried a few things so far, But had no joy with it.

At the moment my code looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UBMLN/)

What I'd like to do is some text animates the same time as the image changes.

Is this possible, If so any help?

Comment: A jsFiddle should only be used to demonstrate functionality, not as a shortcut to avoid typing code.  Please post your code in the question.

Comment: Cycle will cycle whatever you give it - you just need to give it a container that contains a set of whatever you want to cycle.  It can be images, or it can be divs containing their own complex layout.

Comment: I'd like the text to change, roughly at the same time. I think the best way to achieve this is to create one slideshow with the images in it. Another with the HTML content in it. The animation that way appears seemless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was what you were after but let me know either way:

http://jsfiddle.net/UBMLN/1/

Comment: A jsFiddle should only be used to demonstrate functionality, not as a shortcut to avoid typing code. Please post your code in the answer.

Comment: Hi, I'd like the text to change at the same time as the transition, Not with it. I think I might be able to do this by creating 2 slideshows. One for image content, One for HTML

Comment: I see we are getting -1's because we used jsfiddle as an example. Dont quite understand. Damned if you do and damned if you dont on here...

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting jsFiddle examples.  Leaving the code out of the answer is the problem... when the URLs go dead, the answer is totally useless to future readers.

Comment: Not true at all... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171371/how-long-does-jsfiddle-host-your-code-for Sorry but this site is a very useful resource, But some nitty answers you get sometimes are uncalled for!