# Fade from image A to image B, including text?

Tags: javascript, css, image, opacity

So I found this awesome article about fading between images using javascript (using opacity, which works in Mozilla, Opera, and IE): http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script19_fade_image.htm#self

And I'm wondering, can I do the same with text? I mean, if both images have some text inside them, and I want the fade to happen at the same time with text?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can.  I should also note that jQuery wraps this behavior up into a nice convenient package, meaning you can use the same code for all your browsers.  If it is an option for you, I recommend checking it out.

Comment: When you say "images have some text inside them", do you mean the text is part of the image or do you mean you have a separate object near the image that is text?

Comment: this question seems odd.. have you tried just using the exact same method on the text or not?

Comment: jfriend00: if the text was part of the image, my question would not make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to fade between two images, and text, using JQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tr2LA/

Click the image to begin the animation. It works by using JQuery to fade out one div while simultaneously fading in another. Each div contains an image and text.

```
$('#fadeOut').click(function() {

  $('#fadeOut').fadeOut('slow');

  $('#fadeIn').fadeIn('slow');

});
```

Comment: Better (fades back and forth, text centered, padding, cleaner code): http://jsfiddle.net/mnfyz/2

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks D.Strout and Greg! For how long dos jsfiddle retain this mockups?

Comment: You're welcome :) According to this, JSFiddle will host the examples forever: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8191278/1010138. Btw, nice code update, D. Strout.