# Google maps in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsfiddle

I'm trying to implement Google maps in jsFiddle to ask another question, but I can't see the map:
http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/aknYP/

I've added the gmap script in the resources

How can I show the map in jsFiddle?

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.965049,5.484231);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

var contentString = 
    '<div id="infowindow">' +
    'Galaconcert<br />' +
    'Jaarbeurslaan 2-6<br />' +
    '3690 Genk' +
    '</div>'
;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Galaconcert'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
}
```

Comment: You are never calling `initialize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go http://jsfiddle.net/aknYP/4/

You were never calling `initialize()` nor loading the JS Google Maps API

Comment: +1 , it seems a bug in jsfiddle that `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false` don't work when added on **Manage Resources** sidepane but works when setting it in a <script> tag as you did.

Answer (score 11):

As explained [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#choose-framework) under "Add Resources" in a red box:

> Warning: jsFiddle is recognizing the type of the resource by the
>   extension. If you want to use a dynamic resource please add a dummy
>   GET variable i.e. `http://example.com/download/js/dynamically.js?somevar=somevalue&dummy=.js`. This will trick jsFiddle to recognize it as JavaScript resource.

So to make jsFiddle recognize the Google Maps API (which indeed does not have .js extension) you need to add this as the resource: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&dummy=.js (This is in addition to calling initialize of course)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknYP/5/).

Comment: True, it was obvious jsfiddle won't store all the scripts forever however my answer contains no code change just change in an included resource.

Comment: @rbp turns out the OP here manually deleted his fiddles, it's not jsFiddle fault. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171371/how-long-does-jsfiddle-host-your-code-for/8191278?noredirect=1#comment23144599_8191278) by jsFiddle creator.