# My jsfiddle page returns 404 (registration required?)

Tags: jsfiddle

I think jsfiddle is really neat and I used it yesterday to help someone on stackoverflow.

I created a new fiddle, hit 'Save' and used this provided link: http://jsfiddle.net/77XLD/1/

The link was working until a couple of hours ago but suddenly now I get a 404 page when trying to find my old fiddle again. Saying:

```
Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.
```

Now I did **not register** with jsfiddle so far. Does jsfiddle store the pages for an unlimited time only if you are registered there? So did my page somehow just 'time out'?

---

Edit (11th of August 2014):
The page is back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171371/how-long-does-jsfiddle-host-your-code-for?rq=1):

```
Until beta, all fiddles are stored permanently. And, currently, they live forever.
```

My recent Fiddles also ran into 404 errors. And Beta is not out yet, this means that it was a problem on the jsfiddle website itself. If we look at the sites [twitter account](https://twitter.com/jsfiddle) we see that it was a possible DDOS attack causing data loss:

```
All anon fiddles created after July 26th are by now considered 
spammy.. We will resurrect them after filtering out the 99% of real spam.
```

**Update**

According to a new post by jsFiddle:

```
If you’ve created a fiddle anonymously after late July and you remember the 
URL, please let us know, we will resurrect it.
```

So if you have your Fiddles URL's, send them to the people at JSFiddle to get them resurrected.

Comment: :( was a nice fiddle. I surely hope they fix it. Thx for the info!

Answer (score -1):

Long story short: JSFiddle won't store your fiddles for you.

You can contact them and ask them to host it for you over e-mail?  Yeah, you can do that with any website.  That's how e-mail works.  It's not how shared work environment sharing works, though.